# Web crawler to perform task on website

Tags: web-crawler

Can a web crawler be programmed to do the following?

1. Go to https://sitecheck.sucuri.net//
2. Scan specified website using the online tool
3. Return results
4. Bonus question... can this be scheduled to automatically complete this task once daily?

Is it illegal or anything to automatically program a spider to do this?

Any information you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes to questions 1-4. As for legality, you need to ask Sucuri (or interpret their Terms of Service). Some sites will begin blocking your IP address if they don't like how you use their services.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrew for your response. Now all I have to do is find software that allows me to complete this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a crawler for this, a browser automation API like [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) would do the trick. There are various backends that implement the API and clients libraries in different programming languages.

You could also use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) directly by writing a script to load and extract the data from the page.

Either way, a cronscript could call the process once a day.